# background color on polygon figure

Tags: css

I need to set the arrow white background on the same color of the background 
,If I set the  background on blue and the color on white ,the background non covered zone is white  and It should be   at the same color of the container background(some kind of grey)
[Problem image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jlJfK.png)

this is the arrow code

```
#arrow {
    width: 120px;
    height: 40px;
    position: relative;
    background: blue;
    color: white;
    padding-left: 25px;
    padding-top: 5px;
}

#arrow:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 20px solid white;
    border-top: 20px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
}

#arrow:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    right: -20px;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 20px solid blue;
    border-top: 20px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
}
```

I'm not sure about how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an idea with multiple background:

```css
.arrow {
  padding:0 20px;
  color:#fff;
  font-size:25px;
  width:120px;
  text-align:center;
  line-height:50px;
  display:inline-block;
  background:
    /*right arrow*/
    linear-gradient(to bottom left, transparent 49%,blue 50%) top right,
    linear-gradient(to top left, transparent 49%,blue 50%) bottom right,
    /*left arrow*/
    linear-gradient(to bottom left, blue 49%,transparent 50%) top left,
    linear-gradient(to top left, blue 49%,transparent 50%) bottom left,
    
    blue content-box;
  background-size:20px 50%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
    
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow">
  some text
</div>
```

Comment: I'd like to get more info about how you have created the arrow,the gradient on the background do you have  any info that helps me to understand it?

Comment: @Dsfsf basically it's 4 triangles that will create the full shape, each triangle created with a gradient and placed at a corner .. I advice you to change the coloration of each one to better see and you can check this answer for more details : https://stackoverflow.com/a/49696143/8620333

Answer (score 1):

I made more simple with `transform:skew()` property. Solves the your problem exactly.

```css
body {
  background: #333;
  padding:30px;
}

#arrow {
  width: 120px;
  height: 40px;
  position: relative;
  color:#fff;
  font-size:22px;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
}

#arrow::before {
  content:"";
  width: 120px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  background:blue;
  transform:skewX(40deg);
  z-index:-1;
}

#arrow::after {
  content:"";
  width: 120px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top:20px;
  left:0;
  background:blue;
  transform:skewX(-40deg);
  z-index:-1;
}
```

```html
<div id="arrow">Section</div>
```

Comment: Works but the text on the arrow div its down the arrow figure `<div id="arrow"><strong>Text</strong></div>` ,tried with `z-index` but nothing change

Comment: with `z-index:-1`  the arrow its inder the container and its not visible if I set `z-index:` >-1 text its not visible. I think I have to set the z indez of the rest of elements

Comment: I don't know all your codes, and how your site looks.

Comment: @Dsfsf add z-index:0 to the container and keep -1 to the pseudo element to avoid any issue